# Is it feasible to deplatform a user off of SE using a small group of people, and if so how to prevent it

Tags: discussion, serial-voting

Backstory:
I'll start this off by saying my reputation is at 1 for a reason.  Not disputing that.

My main concern is the manner in which this happened.  It's readily apparent that at least two users were involved in deliberately lowering the total number of reputation on my accounts across unrelated questions.  The users in question deliberately down voted several questions/answers of mine which were asked/answered years ago.  This was done across multiple boards on the same day in hours.

Proposal:
If the same approach were used with a larger group of people on a member who they wanted to target, would the approach work on a target with significantly higher reputation then the group in total?  Obviously the amount of damage that can be inflicted on the target increases as their number of interactions with the community increases.  Mathematically would this vector of attack be feasible?  And if so how can such an attack be prevented?

Comment: You can't know that you were targeted by two specific users unless they came out and admitted to it explicitly. And there are scripts in place that automatically reverse excessive targeted voting.

Comment: If this is about your account on [workplace.se], then it might be serial voting which the system should catch that. On the other hand, **please read the [Code of Conduct](https://meta.stackexchange.com/conduct)**. Some of your answers were borderline rude and deserve to be downvoted. Also, apparently you got your posts flagged and deleted for being rude (your reputation change doesn't match your current reputation). **Please consider what you write before you post it**.

Comment: Be sure to follow that advice on my next account.

Comment: Why has this post been downvoted so heavily? Is there some background story that we are not privy to?

Comment: @Mari-LouA: Considering that his workplace account was suspended recently, he probably hasn't been the best user on SE.

Comment: From your profile "BrB gonna go make another account." Creating another account to get around a suspension is also against the rules and will result in your new account being deleted and your suspension increased.

Answer (score 10):

Nope.

If there's serial voting, hopefully the system will catch it.

In theory if you suspect serial voting the script hadn't caught you should flag for a mod, and they may end up escalating to a CM.

We don't know the question and answer ban threshold but it's pretty hard to get question banned - impossible past a certain point actually. So you prevent it by posting great posts and getting upvotes.

If there's a concerted attempt by a large group of people to downvote and close your posts you have other issues.